# What was the point of the hatch?

Tags: lost, architecture

### [Warning](https://youtu.be/IuP__umhFGc?t=3m2s), some spoilers below!

The Swan Station has two entrances, a hatch and a door.

[image: Hatch]

[image: Swan Station door]

The hatch was sealed shut, and it took dynamite to access it. It then opened up to a 50 feet vertical shaft with a ladder.

The door, on the other hand, could be easily opened from the inside. Later on, it was unlocked and could be easily opened from the outside.

So what, exactly, it the point of the hatch? It would be very inconvenient, so it probably wouldn't function well as an alternate exit, even before it was sealed shut. It also wouldn't have a point security-wise, given that the door was fairly noticeable and presumably easier to access.

Comment: Not to be too snarky, but what was the point of the whole show?

Comment: Don't have much to back it up at the moment, but I believe it was the original entrance that they were lowering stuff down into in the 70s, and where that one explosion happened.  The door was probably added later.

Answer (score 8):

According to this floor plan:
[image: Station-3 — The Swan — Upper Level (Floor) Plan View]
                                        <sup>[Source](http://lostified.com/auto/lomm/dharma_swan_floor_plan-3.jpg)</sup>
It’s an emergency exit — item #22, vertical escape shaft.

Comment: What is the source for that image?

Comment: Searched for "Lost Swan Station plan" and the first non-wiki result that comes up is http://lostified.com/docs/lomm/dharma_swan_floor_plan.html. Not sure if that is any help since I can't search in any more detail at present.

Comment: Then why was it sealed shut?

Comment: It was sealed from the inside. You don't want your emergency exit being a security risk.

Comment: In the source page, as provided by @maguirenumber6, the site admin says this is fan art. So... this presumably has no canon status within the series.

Comment: My answer links to the source for the image. (Sorry, I was offline for a while.  And sorry for not checking its authenticity.) The more interesting questions are, why was the ladder in the shaft broken, and would it have been possible for an inhabitant of the station for get to the surface to use the hatch? And why did the station have such a bright light, that could light up the sky like a searchlight?  And why did the Lostians not find the station's main door? — it looks like it wasn't very well hidden.